# Как добавить сразу несколько водяных знаков в видео через MoviePy

Tags: python

Мой код:

```
from moviepy.editor import *
import moviepy.editor as mp

dur = video.duration
video = mp.VideoFileClip('vid.MP4')
logo = (mp.VideoFileClip("logo3.gif", has_mask=True)
    .loop()
    .set_start(1)
    .set_duration(dur/2-2)
    .margin(right=8, top=8, opacity=0)
    .set_pos(("left","top")))

logo2 = (mp.VideoFileClip("logo3.gif", has_mask=True)
    .loop()
    .set_start(dur/2)
    .set_duration(dur/2-4)
    .margin(right=8, top=8, opacity=0)
    .set_pos(("right","bottom")))

final = mp.CompositeVideoClip([video, logo])
final.write_videofile("small_logo.mp4")
```

Как добавить к видео два (и более) разных водяных знака без сохранения на диск?
Пробовал несколько способов с clips_array и т. Д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял [документацию](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/_modules/moviepy/video/compositing/CompositeVideoClip.html):

> ```
> use_bgclip
>
>   Set to True if the first clip in the list should be used as the
>   'background' on which all other clips are blitted. That first clip must
>   have the same size as the final clip. If it has no transparency, the final
>   clip will have no mask.
> ```
>
> Краткий перевод:
>
> Установите `use_bgclip` в `True`, если первый клип в списке должен быть
> использован как "фон" для остальных клипов.

Нужно сделать так:

```
final = mp.CompositeVideoClip([video, logo, logo2], use_bgclip=True)
```

В вашем коде непонятно откуда берётся `clip1`, наверное вы имели в виду `video`, поэтому я заменил на него.